# Workflow for parsing PSD to Xcode/IB

Tags: iphone, ios4, interface-builder, photoshop, nib

i am searching for a way to parse a psd-layout to a nib-file or something like this. I want, that the designer builds a layout and slices this into the different elements. The result should be a ready-to-use XIB-File. ;-)

Are there any ideas how to realize this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can ask your designer to name the difference slices using a specific nomenclature.

A possibility:

```
specific_name-class-x-y-width-height
```

e.g.

```
LoginButton-UIButton-60-200-120-40
```

Then a script parsing each file of your export folder will create your xib file which is nothing more than a XML file.

a simple way to do that could be using [psd.js](http://meltingice.github.com/psd.js/)

But I think that it will be much simpler to teach your designer how to use Interface Builder ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've heard about snippets (.jsx = javaScript??) which you can use for Photoshop. These scripts could export your images/layer/slices and change the name to their relative position. Maybe this information could be helpful for anybody.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial explains exactly how to automatically port a Photoshop PSD or Fireworks Layered PNG into an Xcode storyboard. With all your elements placed for you. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hB5PJgIrUko&sns=em

Answer (score 0):

write your own photoshop script:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html

or, use this service:

http://www.psdtoxib.com/